# Servo motor vs stepper motor

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, servo

This question is to get general idea of servo and stepper motor.

Assume same power rating motor and same voltage rating two motors. Which are servo motor and stepper motor. Same gear ratio.

- what is high torque motor?
- what is high stall torque motor?
- what is high holding torque motor?
- which motor is big size?
- what is high velocity motor?

Assume same size motors which are servo and stepper motor.

- what is high power motor?
- what is high torque motor?

Comment: That’s like comparing MOSFETS to IGBT’s !  What Velocity, Gear Ratio , efficiency, position error, step resolution? Etc

Comment: Same gear ratio and others can be vary

Comment: This is something that can be experimented and observed. Tony has a good list of information that you should consider explaining.

Comment: In general, if the stepper motor and the servo motor are the same physical size you'd expect to see 10:1 to 100:1 more torque from the servo. You can investigate these to get an indication: https://www.teknic.com/products/clearpath-brushless-dc-servo-motors/

Comment: simple answer : SERVO always wins , look at all advanced CNC machines and robotics . the only place where stepper is used is lower cost.

Comment: Torque is always proportional to current so same winding design and core size can give same initial torque vs size, but Servo motors only need current against acceleration profile and load force when static and thus have different complexity and cost a bunch more with incremental encoders and linear PID controlled error. Whereas steppers dont have linear force current feedback unless you estimate what you need to reduce holding current to prevent overheating if opearting at max.  So power and torque can be same or depends on comparing same number of poles and winding type and same core.

Answer (score 2):

A servo motor can be any type of motor that has a control and feedback system that provides precise precise control of angular or linear position, velocity and acceleration of a driven load. For a valid comparison of speed and torque operation range vs. motor mass and volume, it is necessary to consider specific types of servo motors. Feedback devices and their requirements must also be considered.

There are also more than one type of stepper motors. Specific types need to be considered for a valid comparison.

Motor power is torque multiplied by speed. Motor torque is proportional to motor volume. Motor speed is less closely related to motor volume. To some extent, a motor of a given mass and volume can be designed for a specific torque and a wide range of speeds. In this case, the power is determined by the selected speed.

The continuous torque capability is related to the method of removing heat due to losses in the motor. Most motors have a means for the motion of the rotor to move air through the interior and/or over the outer surface of the motor. The physical and design of the motor influence the heat removal capability and thus the continuous torque capability. Higher rotor speed generally means more effective heat removal and higher continuous torque capability.

Not every servo motor is designed to provide continuous, or long term holding torque. Providing continuous torque with no rotor motion may require special cooling provisions or a physically larger motor.